# Fully define a joint CDF of a bivariate distribution using its PDF.

Tags: statistics, multivariable-calculus

Whenever I attempt to find the form of the CDF from a joint PDF I always get confused about the limits and how to approach them. For example, the question I am attempting is:

Find the joint CDF of $X$ and $Y$, given that the PDF is $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \frac{1}{4}(x+2y)$ for $0<x<1$ and $0<y<2$, and is $0$ otherwise.

I know the following:
$$F_{X,Y}(x,y) = P(X\le x, Y\le y) = \int_{-\infty}^{x} \int_{-\infty}^{y} f_{X,Y}(v,u)\ dv \ du$$
in our case that would be:
\begin{align*}
F_{X,Y}(x,y) & = \int_{0}^{x} \int_{0}^{y} \frac{1}{4} (u+2v)\ dv du \\
         & =  \frac{1}{4} \int_{0}^{x}uy+y^2\ du\\
         & = \frac{1}{4} \left[\frac{x^2y}{2} + xy^2\right] = \frac{x^2y}{8} + \frac{xy^2}{4}
\end{align*}

for $0<x<1$ and $0<y<2$.

But since this is a CDF, I need to have it defined for all values of $x$ and $y$. How should I approach this and what is the logic behind the approach? Perhaps I should consider all possible limits before even attempting to find the CDF, but how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that I have solved this particular question and have pinned down the approach towards this kind of questions. Please do feel free to comment/edit since I am aware my wording is not ideal.

What we would like to do is to consider the values of $x$ and $y$ outside of the support of $X$ and $Y$ as well as in it. So in our case, the support of $X$ is $(0,2)$ while the support of $Y$ is $(0,1)$. We would like to consider, when evaluating $F_{X,Y}(x,y) = P(X \le x, Y \le y)$, the cases when:

- either $x$ or $y$ are always smaller the support of $X$ or $Y$,
- both $x$ and $y$ are in the support of $X$ and $Y$,
- $x$ is always greater than the support of $X$, while $y$ is in the support of $Y$,
- $y$ is always greater than the support of $Y$, while $x$ is in the support of $X$,
- both $x$ and $y$ are always greater than the support of $X$ and $Y$.

So, in addition to the evaluations performed above for when the values of $x$ and $y$ are in the support of $X$ and $Y$, consider intervals outside the support of the random variables. For $x\le 0$ or $y\le 0$, no value from the support of $X$: $(0,2)$, or the support of $Y$: $(0,1)$ will ever be realised, so 
$$F_{X,Y}(x,y) = P(X\le x, Y\le y) = P(X\le 0, Y\le 0) = 0,$$

For $2 \le x$, $0<y<1$ we would have:
$$ F_{X,Y}(x,y) = F(X\le x, Y\le y) = P(X\le 2,Y \le y) = \int_{0}^{y} \int_{0}^{2} \frac{1}{4} (u+2v) \ du dv = \frac{y}{2} + \frac{y^2}{2},$$

For $0< x < 2$, $1\le y$ we would have:
$$ F_{X,Y}(x,y) = F(X\le x, Y\le y) = P(X\le x, Y\le 1) = \int_{0}^{x} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{4} (v+2u) \ du dv = \frac{x^2}{8} + \frac{x}{4},$$

For $2 \le x, 1\le y$, we would have $F(X\le x, Y\le y) = F(X\le 2, Y\le 1) = 1$.

Therefore, the complete definition of $F_{X,Y}$ is:

$$
F_{X,Y}(x,y)=
 \begin{cases}
 0 &  x \le 0 \text{ or } y\le 0,\\
 \frac{x^2y}{8} + \frac{xy^2}{4} &  0<x<2, 0<y<1,\\
 \frac{y}{2} + \frac{y^2}{2} &  2 \le x, 0<y<1,\\
 \frac{x^2}{8} + \frac{x}{4} &  0< x < 2, 1\le y,\\
 1 & 2 \le x, 1\le y.
 \end{cases}
$$